# Wash-sale Cost Basis Adjustment question

Tags: united-states, stocks, capital-gains-tax, wash-sale, cost-basis

I wonder about the Adjustments to Cost Basis after a wash sale occur. Considering this [Example 1](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/understanding-the-wash-sale-rules-2015-03-02) ( from marketwatch.com) where someone:

On 1 Dec, 2018 used an amount of money in his account to buy 100 shares of XYZ Co., for $2000 (to make it simple , let's say 1 Feb, 2019 to turn all the transactions into the same year)

On 1 Apr, 2019 he sells the shares for $1200, and incurred a loss of 800$.

On 10 Apr, 2019 he bought back 100 shares for $1300, and had a wash sale. The 800$ loss gets added to the cost basis of this transaction( and the basis becomes $2100)

Now, If on 13 Apr 2019, he sold 100 shares for $1400; I'm pretty sure that the realized Gain/Loss record of this transaction would show something like this: " XYZ Co. shares  100 , Proceeds $1400 , Cost basis  $2100(adjusted), Short-term Gain/Loss  -$700 ". So, even though the Gain/Loss shows a negative number, he still got an actual profit of $100 from this sale, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wash sale accounting doesn't change the amount of the gains or  losses, just possibly when you can claim them.

Buy at $20, sell at $12 is an $8 loss and buy at $13 and sell at $14 is a $1 gain - for a total loss of $7.

Adjusting the cost basis due to the wash sale just shifts the cost basis around but the answer is still the same, a total loss of $7.

This would only become a tax issue if the $800 wash sale loss occurred in one tax year and the replacement shares were not sold until the following year (a carryover wash sale violation).  You'd still have the same total loss but claiming it would occur on two different tax returns.

Comment: In this scenario, after the sale of 100 shares for $1400 (in April), he doesn't trade XYZ stock anymore. Instead, he trades other A, B, C, .... stocks. Does the $700 loss count to offset the realized gains in other securites?

Comment: If you buy the shares back within 30 days after everything has been sold, you have a new wash sale.  If you wait 31 days (or never trade that stock again) then the $700 loss is in the books and is  fully deductible.

Comment: Good to know. Because, in the articles, they said wash-sale losses are not allowed for tax benefits; I assumed once the wash sale occurred, the loss would stay in the record of the year as non-deductible loss.

Comment: The only time that you lose the loss is if the wash sale replacement shares are bought in your IRA

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up info. Luckily, my trading account is a regular non-IRA brokerage account.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add a tabular example to understand the [share cost basis adjustment resulting from a wash sale](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wash_sale&oldid=997522841).

Let's assume the following trade history on Stock A:

| Date | Action | Stock A price | Gain/loss | Commutative Gain/loss |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-02-07 | Buy 100 of stock A | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-03-17 | Sell 100 of stock A | 20 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 2020-03-22 | Buy 100 of stock A | 18 | 0 | 1000 |
| 2020-03-29 | Sell 100 of stock A | 3 | -1500 | -500 |
| 2020-04-10 | Buy 50 of stock A | 2 | 0 | -500 |
| 2020-04-15 | Sell 50 of stock A | 3 | 50 | -450 |
| 2020-05-15 | No activity on stock A | 3 | 0 | -450 |

This will result in the following tax activities:

| Row | Date | Action | Stock A price | Stock A cost basis | Gain/loss | Cumulative Gain/loss | Taxed Capital Gains | Cumulative Taxed Capital Gains |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-02-07 | Buy 100 of stock A | 10 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2020-03-17 | Sell 100 of stock A | 20 | 20 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 3 | 2020-03-22 | Buy 100 of stock A | 18 | 18 | 0 | 1000 | 0 | 1000 |
| 4 | 2020-03-29 | Sell 100 of stock A | 3 | 3 | -1500 | -500 | -1500 | -500 |
| 5 | 2020-04-10 | Buy 50 of stock A | 2 | 2 + (18-3) = 17 | 0 | -500 | 1500*(50/100) =750 | 250 |
| 6 | 2020-04-15 | Sell 50 of stock A | 3 | 3 | 50 | -450 | (3-17)*50 =-700 | -450 |
| 7 | 2020-05-15 | No activity on stock A | 3 | NA | 0 | -450 | 0 | -450 |

Notes:

- Row 5: The change in Stock A cost basis during the stock purchase results from the wash sale in row 4. I.e., the wash sale loss (a.k.a. *disallowed loss*) is added to the basis of the replacement stock. Since the individual purchased 50 replacement shares whereas the preceding sale involved 100 shares, only 50 shares are considered to be part of the wash sale, hence 1500*(**50/100**)=750 USD.
- Row 6: Whereas the sale of 50 shares of Stock A caused a capital gain of 50 USD,  from the tax standpoint it reduced the amount of capital gain tax by (3-17)*50=-700 USD, since 17 USD is the cost basis that was used in row 5 when purchasing the 50 shares of Stock A.
- I assume that all trades took place in a taxable brokerage account. See [Wash sale rules between tax-advantaged and regular accounts](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/21450/5656) for tax-advantagious accounts.
- [Feature request to add an option to display the table full screen (or at the least some larger view) when viewing a table as a reader, since it is quite annoying to do the horizontal scrolling for wide tables.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360685/178179)

Comment: I totally understand table 1. But, for table 2, after having tried pretty hard to understand it, I still can't understand the "stock A cost basis", and "Taxed Capital Gains" columns from row 5 going down. I only can get it from my perspective, which is: since only 50 shares purchased in row 5 subject to wash-sale adjustment, $750 from $1500 loss are not allowed, instead added to the cost basis, and results in a cost basis of $850( 100+750), meaning a cost basis per share of $17( 850/50). And, $750 loss is still allowed, results in a cumulative taxed capital gain of $250.

Comment: And,yes,those transactions took place in a taxable brokerage account.The columns in the hypothetical examples are actually the column titles in my TD ameritrade Realized P/L report. The dollar amounts are not the same,but the idea is very similar. I want to understand the wash-sale adjustments, since I often place multiple trades on the same stock. Although I don't totally get your table 2 ,but the idea still holds, that wash-sale losses are still counted and tax-deductible,as long as the trades are in a brokerage account,based on sources that you guys refer to. Anyway, thanks for your answer!